# how to check whether a set of 10,000 consecutive ports are open on my pc at localhost?

Tags: tcp, cmd, port, server

All in all i want 10000 open ports at localhost  and that too consecutive like 55000 to 65000 for my project .I want to be sure that the set(10,000 consecutive ports)  of ports are open .

Here i am describing the three categories of ports:-

## The Well Known Ports are those from 0 through 1023.

## The Registered Ports are those from 1024 through 49151

## The Dynamic and/or Private Ports are those from 49152 through 65535

I want to know some cmd command which will solve my purpose.(i am using windows OS).

## My System supports netstat but i want some other command or tool to solve my purpose   as i find netstat very time consuming and manual way of checking.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of Windows? You sure you can't use netstat? This [site](http://support.kaspersky.com/general/various/101) suggests you can.  Do you have [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com) installed?  If you install that, you can get a LOT of Linux like utilities on your  Windows box.

Comment: Sir .Please read the question properly .I have mentioned that i want to know some other command for my specific purpose and regarding netstat my windows version(windows 7 ultimate) does support that , but i find that a manual way of checking .I hope you have got my point now .

Comment: Why? Any project that needs 10,000 ports has something seriously wrong with it, and any project that thinks it needs *consecutive* ports is mis-designed and over-specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Windows *does* have a `netstat` which you can process the output of to look for established sessions:

```
C:\pax> netstat -na

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    10.6.0.127:54140       143.127.136.95:443     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    10.6.0.127:54259       192.168.2.47:32308     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    10.6.0.127:54263       192.168.2.47:32308     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    10.6.0.127:54274       192.168.2.22:50207     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    10.6.0.127:54319       192.168.2.40:5061      ESTABLISHED
```

But I've finally given up on `cmd.exe` as a scripting language.

---

You can also use `get-nettcpconnection` from within Powershell to get similar information:

```
PS C:\pax> Get-NetTCPConnection
           | format-table -autosize

LocalAddress LocalPort RemoteAddress   RemotePort State       AppliedSetting
------------ --------- -------------   ---------- -----       --------------
::           54122     ::              0          Listen
::           54104     ::              0          Listen
::           49156     ::              0          Listen
::           445       ::              0          Listen
::           135       ::              0          Listen
10.6.0.127   56321     10.4.0.96       445        Established Internet
127.0.0.1    56053     127.0.0.1       8085       TimeWait
127.0.0.1    56052     127.0.0.1       8085       TimeWait
10.6.0.127   56046     192.168.2.13    445        Established Internet
127.0.0.1    56043     127.0.0.1       8085       TimeWait
10.6.0.127   56039     192.168.2.13    49814      Established Internet
10.6.0.127   56038     192.168.2.13    135        TimeWait
10.6.0.127   56035     216.58.220.142  443        Established Internet
: : :
```

The Powershell way is preferred, at least by intelligent people such as I :-) since it has all these fantastic capabilities for filtering and modifying the data:

```
PS C:\pax> get-nettcpconnection
           | where-object {$_.State -eq 'Established'}
           | select-object 'LocalPort'
           | sort-object 'LocalPort'
           | format-table -autosize

LocalPort
---------
    23560
    49735
    49736
    54140
    54145
    54259
    54263
    : : :
```

Any more complex processing (like finding 10,000 consecutive connections) can be done in a `PS1` script, similar to how it would have been done with `CMD` files in the past.